# Firebase authentication with Strava provider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I would like people  to sign in with there Strava account (strava is a cycling/running platform)

Firebase has some default authentication Sign-in providers like Google, twitter etc. but no Strava. Is there any other way I can authenticate users via there Strava account in Firebase?

My project is in AngularJS

[Strava authentication API documents](http://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/)

Comment: have you tried adding Strava as a custom authentication system? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Comment: @leandro The way that I understand it you need to be the owner of the authentication server. According to custom authentication docs you have to create credentials and download a key pair file and place in on the authentication server, Strava is the authentication server and I have no acces to there server.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is a limited list of OAuth providers supported by [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/provisioning/configure-oauth#add-idp).

If you just want people to be Authenticated against your application I would suggest to implement the OAuth flow by yourself in your client application.

If you also want to store some user state and therefore want to use Firebase you could create a Firebase User Account for every ID Token you receive from your Oauth-Client. People can sign up /sign in to your Firebase backend by providing their ID Token and exchanging it against a Firebase Access token.

Important: Make sure to verify the Strava Id/Access token in some way. Simplest way would be to call the Strava API and see if the token gets accepted.